# Oops! Something Bad Happened! Developer CV

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was trying to see my developer CV and suddenly this error came. https://stackoverflow.com/cv/dencygb got redirected to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fso-proxy%2Fcv%2Fdencygb.

I'd like to know in detail about it.